En Android como envío una imagen a un nuevo chat de Whatsapp?
Quiero adjuntar en automático la imagen que quiero enviar a un número que no está en mis contactos.
Con el siguiente código puedo adjuntar el archivo pero solo puedo enviarlo a un chat existente.
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri)
    intent.setType("image/*")
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, whatsappMessage)
    intent.setType("text/plain")
    intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp")
    startActivity(intent)

Con este código puedo abrir un nuevo chat, pero no sé como adjuntar la imagen al mismo tiempo.
val url = "whatsapp://send?phone=$phoneNumber&text=${
        URLEncoder.encode(
            whatsappMessage,
            "UTF-8"
        )
    }"
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    intent.data = Uri.parse(url)
    startActivity(intent)

Espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias de antemano ✌️

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! android studio no es la ide??? la pregunta seria mejor, en el lenguaje kotlin y con la api de whatsapp como hacer esto???
